# Seems something wrong with my Include with Where query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

Please note, these are just Main Category and Sub Category (Level1Set, Level2Set)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waNf5.jpg)

My models respectively:

```
    public class Level1Set

    public int Id { get; set; }
    [StringLength(42)]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Level2Set> Level2Sets { get; set; }

    public class Level2Set

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
    public int? Level1SetId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual Level1Set Level1Set { get; set; }
```

I am using for first time Include with Where query but it all seemed mundane. Most examples are for Lists result though.

I want to pull just one Sub Category for Edit and include which Main Category it belongs to.

```
var result = dBcontext.Level1Sets
                      .Include(l2 => l2.Level2Sets.Where(c => c.Id == id.Value))
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

So, for Id=1, I get correct result. For Id=2 or 3 however I get fully wrong result. No Sub Category and incorrect Main Category.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YG7kO.jpg)

What is incorrect here and eventually what would be the right query for this case. Besides two call to the DB.

Thank you.

Comment: i am not sure if i understand the question correctly but it seams like you want to get all level2 that are related to level1. `dBcontext.Level1Sets.Include(l2 => l2.Levell2Sets).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id.Value)`

Comment: No. I want only one Level2Set for Edit with corresponding one Levell1Set Name. 
I need this Name just to designate which Main Category the edited Sub Category belongs to.

Comment: ah i think i got it you want a level2Set by Id and  get the level1 on related to it? 
`dBcontext.Level2Sets.Include(x => x.Level1Set).FirstOrDefault(l2 => l2.Id == id.Value)`

Comment: It works. Thank you jeb . What would be the best thing I could do for you now ? Like voting etc. ?? And for the others that might come to help in that matter. I have been using SO for many years but only for researches.

For the topic, it leaves me puzzled - if we use FirstOrDefault for the predicate, then what is the WHERE for ??
Also, how your query know that "l2" is for the Leel2Sets ??  mean the other model has Id too. Any tutorials to point to ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you take the entity that you want to query and then include from there. In you case it's a Level2Sets.

```
dBcontext.Level2Sets.Include(x => x.Level1Set).FirstOrDefault(l2 => l2.Id == id.Value)
```

Regarding your followup question:

> if we use FirstOrDefault for the predicate, then what is the WHERE
> for ?

the Where would be required if you need more then one entity based on a condition. for example:

```
dBcontext.Level1Sets.Include(l2 => l2.Level2Sets.Where(c => c.IsActive)).FirstOrDefault();
```

So you would get one Level1Sets and all related Level2Sets that are active

Comment: jeb, please once again - the predicate in the FirstOrDefault will be for the very first entity, i.e. the one right after dBContext, regardless of how many Include(s) we may have after that ?? Is that what you say as rule of a thumb ??
Just yes, or no :)

Comment: Yes you could include set2 .ThenInclude set3 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to extract the Level2Set with the name of Level1Set

You can use the following two methods

1.Use Include(Left join are produced)

```
 var resulst = context.Level2Set.Include(l2 => l2.Level1Set)
         .Select(d => new { a = d, Level1Setname = d.Level1Set.Name 
         }).FirstOrDefault(c => c.a.Id == Id);
```

Query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1) [l].[Id], 
           [l].[IsActive], [l].[Level1SetId], [l].[Name],
            [l0].[Id], [l0].[IsActive], [l0].[Name]
FROM [Level2Set] AS [l]
LEFT JOIN [Level1Set] AS [l0] ON [l].[Level1SetId] = [l0].[Id]
WHERE [l].[Id] = @__Id_0',N'@__Id_0 int',@__Id_0=4
```

2.Use join(inner join are produced)

```
 var innerJoin = context.Level2Set.Join(
                         context.Level1Set,
                      a => a.Level1SetId,
                      b => b.Id,
                      (a, b) => new { 
                   a = a, Level1Setname = b.Name 
               }).FirstOrDefault(d => d.a.Id == Id);
```

Query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1) [l].[Id], 
[l].[IsActive], [l].[Level1SetId], 
[l].[Name], [l0].[Name] AS [Level1Setname]
FROM [Level2Set] AS [l]
INNER JOIN [Level1Set] AS [l0] 
    ON [l].[Level1SetId] = [l0].[Id]
WHERE [l].[Id] = @__Id_0',N'@__Id_0 int',@__Id_0=4
```

Comment: Thank you abolfazl sadeghi. Your answer is very helpful too. I wish I could vote it too as Accepted.

Comment: @ILIIACHTEREV, your welcome,no problem, It is important for me to help you, You can  upvote with flash up

Comment: abolfazl sadeghi , please excuse my ignorance. I have thousands of researches on SO but for first time I am asking and dealing with all functionality.
So flash up I guess means the upper pointing triangle. I already did that but it says I need 15 votes before it starts counting.